# Structure of equientropic transformations

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Given a probability vector $v=(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ with $1\geq v_i\geq 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i=1$ its entropy can be defined as:
$$
H(v):=-\sum_{i=1}^nv_i\log v_i
$$
I wonder what is known about transformations that leave the entropy of the vector unchanged. That is, given $v$, a map $T:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ that takes probability vectors to probability vectors and verifies $H(v)=H(T(v))$.

A permutation would be a trivial one. For  extremal vector $(0,\ldots ,1,\ldots,0)$ this would be the only solution. However, in general, there is an infinity of valid transformations. Is anything known about the structure of these maps?

Comment: Not clear in general. For example there the vectors $(1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4)$ and $(1/2,1/8,1/8,1/8,1/8)$ give the same entropy, but even if you fix the size of your vector there are many that give the same entropy. I have not seen any result about such transformations $T$.

Comment: You can think of equi-entropy contours on the probability simplex. The shape of these are often shown in papers, but unfortunately, I don't have a reference on top of my head. EDIT: here's one https://books.google.com/books?id=oJSkBXWctsgC&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=isoentropy+contours+simplex&source=bl&ots=IlFyKhBRnJ&sig=3V9nQgB-cetVvz4y5XWwNwu8b1M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=InPiVLrCOazgsAST2IDgDw&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=isoentropy%20contours%20simplex&f=false and http://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.6440.pdf

Comment: I understand that you can draw equientropic contours on the simplex, but I would expect (or more precisely like) points with equal entropy to have some underlying structure

Comment: @Memming no answer so far and the bounty expires in a couple of days. If you want to expand your comment into an answer I would accept it (provide it no other answer appears)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a visualization of the isoentropy contours on 3 variable simplex (from [Information Theoretic Learning: Renyi’s Entropy and Kernel Perspectives](http://amzn.to/1vlvROi). Disclaimer: I contributed to a chapter in this book).

[image]

You could find what local changes can be applied by studying the tangent of the manifold perhaps.